# Hacer tabla de comparacion con diferente length de arrays

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs

Le comento, estoy intentando hacer la típica tabla de pricing o de comparaciones entre productos de mismas categorías, en las cuales, cuando generalmente el pricing es más caro o el producto tienes más características, se le van sumando checks a sus características o features, dejo un ejemplo X para que se entienda mejor:

[image: Ejemplo:]

Actualmente, estoy en un proyecto en React JS.

Tengo un componente al cual le llega una variable por props mapeada con nombre "sizes", la cual al hacer un console.log(sizes) me imprime lo siguiente:

```
0: {name: "King", slug: "king"}
1: {name: "Individual", slug: "individual"}
2: {name: "Super", slug: "pro"}
3: {name: "Queen", slug: "queen"}
length: 4

ProdDetail.js?dfd1:66 
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: "Regular", slug: "regular"}
1: {name: "King", slug: "king"}
2: {name: "Individual", slug: "individual"}
3: {name: "Super", slug: "pro"}
4: {name: "XL King", slug: "xl-king"}
length: 5

ProdDetail.js?dfd1:66 
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: "King", slug: "king"}
1: {name: "Individual", slug: "individual"}
2: {name: "Super", slug: "pro"}
3: {name: "Queen", slug: "queen"}
```

Lo que busco, es poder hacer una comparación, en la que, cuando encuentre que alguno de estos valores "name" dentro del array es diferente al otro (o no lo tiene mejor dicho), en vez de renderizar y pintar solo los elementos que que tiene este array, quiero que mantenga el length del mayor y que en caso de no poseer dicho valor, poner como valor una "X" o simplemente un "---" para mostrar que NO posee ese nombre o característica.

en este caso, buscaría algo similar a esto:

[image: Output]

hasta el momento estoy en esto, pero nada... nada cerca de lo que busco

```
const sizes = arr.map((el) => {
  return el.name.toString().length;
});

console.log(Math.max(...sizes));

tambien probe algo como mapear sizes con un index y recorrerlo e ir comparando o hacer un "includes" pero no compara lo que no tiene el array por lo que entrega solo true
```

Por favor me ayudaría mucho su ayuda, ya que no logro dar con algún método que al iterar me vaya comparando los arrays y entregue lo que necesito.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: Por favor agrega lo que has intentado hasta el momento.

Comment: Podrías pasar como prop, ademas de sizes, al array con el length mayor a cada componente para que puedas comparar las propiedades de uno con el otro usando algún método como Object.keys. Si puedes comparte el código  y JSX del componente y del parent que le pasa a sizes como prop

Answer (score 0):

En este ejemplo que te muestro, tome las respuestas que mostraste arriba para poder obtener un ejemplo similar al que mencionar, lamentablemente como no compartiste el codigo no podria decirte como hacerlo con tu logica que tienes implementada.

En este ejemplo utilizo la libreria llamada RamdaJS, es muy util en esta clase de casos y espero que al usarla no dañe la respuesta que te estare dando, la razon por la que la uso es que el codigo queda mucho mas legible y corto que si utilizara vanilla javascript.

Para importar la libraria en tu caso con react deberias de hacer lo siguiente.

Instalar la libraria
`npm install ramda`

Importar el modulo
`import * as R from "ramda"`

Abajo en el codigo explicare el codigo con comentarios.

```js
const table1 = [
  { name: "King", slug: "king" },
  { name: "Individual", slug: "individual" },
  { name: "Super", slug: "pro" },
  { name: "Queen", slug: "queen" },
];

const table2 = [
  { name: "Regular", slug: "regular" },
  { name: "King", slug: "king" },
  { name: "Individual", slug: "individual" },
  { name: "Super", slug: "pro" },
  { name: "XL King", slug: "xl-king" },
];

const table3 = [
  { name: "King", slug: "king" },
  { name: "Individual", slug: "individual" },
  { name: "Super", slug: "pro" },
  { name: "Queen", slug: "queen" },
];

// Aqui lo que hacemos es unir los arreglos de las tres tablas 
// y filtrar el arreglo de manera que solo queden los datos sin
// repetirse para obtener de esta manera todos los valores posibles
// que habra en las tablas.

// R.pipe ejecuta varias funciones en secuencia
// R.prop obtiene el valor de la propiedad indicada (en este caso "name")
// R.uniqueWith evalua los valores del arreglo y obtiene elementos sin
// repetir de acuerdo a la condicion.
// R.eqBy es la condicion en este caso que debe ser el unico string existente
// por lo cual no podras tener dos strings iguales en todo el arreglo.
const arrayNameValue = R.pipe(
  R.map(R.prop("name")),
  R.uniqWith(R.eqBy(String))
)([...table1, ...table2, ...table3]);

// Esta funcion lo que consigue es evaluar una tabla de forma que obtendrias
// un arreglo con valores de true o false pero de igual forma podrian ser
// cambiados en tu caso por una x y una palomita.
const arrayFiltered = (table) =>
  arrayNameValue.map((x) =>
    R.find(R.propEq("name", x))(table) === undefined ? false : true
  );

console.log(arrayFiltered(table1));
console.log(arrayFiltered(table2));
console.log(arrayFiltered(table3));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```